# make css menu sub links display vertical rather than horizontal

Tags: html, css

I have this CSS for my horizontal menu:

```
.vertical-nav {
    height:auto;
    list-style:none;
    margin: 20px 0 0 0;
}
.vertical-nav li {
    height: 25px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px 0;
    background-color: #666;
    border: none;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    min-width: 125px;  /******* MODIFIED ********/
}
.vertical-nav li:hover {
    background-color:#f36f25;
    color:#FFFFFF;
}
.vertical-nav li a {
    font-family:Calibri, Arial;
    font-size:18px;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#ffffff;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.vertical-nav li.current {
    background-color:#F36F25;
}
.vertical-nav li.current a {
    color:#FFFFFF;
}
vertical-nav ul li ul {
    display:none;
    list-style-type:none;
    width:125px;
    padding:0px;
    margin-top:3px;
    margin-left:-5px;
}
vertical-nav ul li:hover ul {
    display:block;
}
vertical-nav ul li:hover ul li {
    background-color:#555555;
    width:125px;
    height:30px;
    display:inline-block;
}
vertical-nav ul li ul li:hover {
    background-color:#333333;
}
vertical-nav ul li ul li a {
    color:#FFF;
    text-decoration:underline;
}
vertical-nav ul li ul li a:hover {
    text-decoration:none;
}
.vertical-nav li ul {
    display: none;
    margin-top: 6px;
    padding: 0;
}
.vertical-nav li:hover ul {
    display: block;
}
```

but the sub menu links are displaying horizontally rather than vertically...

whats the best way to change the CSS to make this to make the sub links display vertical rather than horizontal?

here is the HTML of the menu:

```
<ul class="vertical-nav">
<li><a href="index.php">Link</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
        <li><a href="index.php">Sub Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.php">Sub Link</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.sub-menu li
{
    clear: both;
}
```

Add the above CSS. **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9AT2D/1/)**

Comment: thats it - but if i have a long name the whole width of the link changes. http://jsfiddle.net/9AT2D/3/ - is there a way to make the parent links the same width but the sub menu links the width of the name without changing the width of parent link

Comment: .vertical-nav {width: 200px; } likewise you can alter the width.

Comment: i have done this now - http://jsfiddle.net/9AT2D/4/ - so the sub menu links are 200px but what happens if the name is longer as they are automatically generated from a MySQL Database. can i make it a percentage?

Comment: .vertical-nav li {
width: 200px; } currently it is min-width, make it width.

Comment: Could you please post it as a different question. Giving 100% will only extend upto width of parent div. The only option is to adjust with by ourselves depending upon the content.

Answer (score 0):

Like this

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xmgMq/)**

**CSS**

```
.vertical-nav {
    height:auto;
    list-style:none;
    width: 400px; /******* MODIFIED ********/
    margin: 20px 0 0 0;
}
.vertical-nav li {
    height: 25px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px 0;
    background-color: #666;
    border: none;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    width: 200px;  /******* MODIFIED ********/
}
.vertical-nav li:hover {
    background-color:#f36f25;
    color:#FFFFFF;
}
.vertical-nav li a {
    font-family:Calibri, Arial;
    font-size:18px;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#ffffff;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.vertical-nav li.current {
    background-color:#F36F25;
}
.vertical-nav li.current a {
    color:#FFFFFF;
}
vertical-nav ul li ul {
    display:none;
    list-style-type:none;
    width:125px;
    padding:0px;
    margin-top:3px;
    margin-left:-5px;
}
vertical-nav ul li:hover ul {
    display:block;
}
vertical-nav ul li:hover ul li {
    background-color:#555555;
    width:125px;
    height:30px;
    display:inline-block;
}
vertical-nav ul li ul li:hover {
    background-color:#333333;
}
vertical-nav ul li ul li a {
    color:#FFF;
    text-decoration:underline;
}
vertical-nav ul li ul li a:hover {
    text-decoration:none;
}
.vertical-nav li ul {
    display: none;
    margin-top: 6px;
    padding: 0;
}
.vertical-nav li:hover ul {
    display: block;
}
```